# VBA ADODB.recordset with Oracle Database

Tags: vba, oracle

im trying to update a ADODB.recordset to update Data in an Oracle Database.
When i Edit "simple Fields" like a number or a String, all works perfectly, but right now im trying to update a TIMESTAMP(6) Field in an Oracle Datebase.

This is the part of the "update Field" the update process works perfectly for Field(7) and everything else, but not for the Timestamp (6) Field.
Im pretty sure there is some mistake in the Format, but i already tried several formats, and the format which i chosed right now is the on i get as an output after i read data from the oracleDB.

```
' Update                                                                                                  ' --------------------------------------------------
    recset.Fields(7).Value = "DELETE"
    recset.Fields(2).Value = "6/7/2023 9:56:25 AM"
    ADN = recset.Fields(2).Value




    recset.Update
    recset.MoveNext                                                                                                  '       next Data
    recset.Close
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You try to insert a string rather than a `Date` value. Try `recset.Fields(2).Value = CDate("2023-07-06 09:56:25")` (or `TimeValue("2023-07-06 09:56:25")`)